# Execute a .cgi file in Ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu, apache2, cgi

I am running Apache/PHP under Ubuntu

When I run the .cgi file, by going at `http://localhost/mycgi.cgi`, the browser will display the code instead of running it.

How do I make the browser execute the CGI file instead of showing its contents?

Comment: Voting to migrate to http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @daxim: I don't think that this really is a ubuntu specific problem. The question is located correct here.

Answer (score 13):

Add these lines to your apache2.conf file

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/somedir>
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>

AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

Comment: +1 short and simple. When using on a virtual host, you need to specify this option in a <Directory> tag inside of <VirtualHost> tag, "Options +ExecCGI" has no effect on <VirtualHost> alone.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, `CGI` execution is not set up properly. Did you try the [tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html)?

Usually, all `CGI` scripts are put into a certain location such as `cgi-bin`. Only the files present in that folder are executed at all. Otherwise, they are treated as normal files and the web server simply returns them as source.

The [tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html) shows you the alternatives that you can use to make the scripts being executed instead of just being returned as text files.

Comment: I did create a cgi-bin in the usr/www/mywww/cgi-bin
is that what you mean?
If not where else should I put it?

Comment: @Jean: just creating a `cgi-bin` directory is **not** sufficient. Do yourself a favor and read the tutorial. They explain things very well there.

Comment: that tutorial is dung imo. e.g. "The ScriptAlias directive looks like:
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/ The example shown is from your default httpd.conf configuration file, if you installed Apache in the default location" this wasn't true for me

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the shebang line in your .cgi or .pl file is correct. The shebang line tells Apache where the Perl interpreter is (the Perl interpreter is the perl.exe file).

The Apache tutorial says:

> Your first CGI program
>   The following is an example CGI program that prints one line to your browser. Type in the following, save it to a file called first.pl, and put it in your cgi-bin directory. #!/usr/bin/perl
>   print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
>   print "Hello, World.";

So here the shebang line is `#!/usr/bin/perl`

**However**, if perl.exe is located in a different folder, then `#!/usr/bin/perl` needs to be changed! This is true even for Windows users who, normally, can completely ignore and omit the shebang line. (Why the tutorial doesn't mention this fact, i don't know - i guess they didn't realise that some people always ignore the shebang line?)

For example, when I installed Perl it was automatically suggested that i install Perl in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Perl64`
Inside my Perl64 folder is folder called 'bin' and inside that is perl.exe

So i had to change the shebang line to: `#!C:/Program Files (x86)/Perl64/bin/perl.exe`
before i could get cgi scripts to work with Apache.

Answer (score 0):

This foxed me on Amazon Ubuntu 14.04. I had a configuration that had 'worked' for a few years:

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Sorted this out for some existing Perl scripts with a .cgi extension and the existing virtual host configuration. Also wrong [not this problem but associated with this upgrade]:

```
virtual.host
```

needed to become

```
virtual.host.conf
```

before it was recognised as valid.